# java connectivity with mysql error

Tags: java, jdbc

I just started with the connectivity and tried this example. I have installed the necessary softwares. Also copied the jar file into the /ext folder.Yet the code below has the following error

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Jdbc00 {
  public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
      Statement stmt;

          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          String url =
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"
            DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "root");

      //Display URL and connection information
      System.out.println("URL: " + url);
      System.out.println("Connection: " + con);

      //Get a Statement object
      stmt = con.createStatement();

      //Create the new database
      stmt.executeUpdate(
                       "CREATE DATABASE JunkDB");

      stmt.executeUpdate(
          "GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE," +
          "CREATE,DROP " +
          "ON JunkDB.* TO 'auser'@'localhost' " +
          "IDENTIFIED BY 'drowssap';");
      con.close();
    }catch( Exception e ) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }//end catch
  }//end main
}//end class Jdbc00
```

But it gave the following error

```
D:\Java12\Explore>java Jdbc00
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Jdbc00.main(Jdbc00.java:11)
```

Could anyone please guide me in correcting this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar file that contains the MySQL driver class (`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`) isn't being found on the classpath when you run your application. This is what the `ClassNotFoundException` is complaining about.

You'll need to add it either to the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, or using the classpath option when running Java. For example:

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar Jdbc00
```

Use the name and location of whatever MySQL connector jar file you're using. (If you haven't already installed MySQL on localhost, so your application has something to connect to, you might have to do that too.)

Answer (score 1):

As @Ash says, the problem is that the Connector/J drivers are not on your classpath.  You can download the latest version (5.0.12) from [this page](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).